# Node js not recognizing input fields that were added dynamically to the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I saw a similar question but did not know how to apply it to node js.  I created a cart, a user clicks to add an item and that item is added to the form using jquery. On submit however, the only form field acknowledge is the `totalCost` which was not dynamically added.

My pug file (the relevant portion):

```
h1#spendable 50000
table
    form#cartitems(method='POST' action='/store')
        tbody
            tr#buyit(style='border-bottom:0px solid white; height:50px; display:none;')
                td#purchCost <b> Total: </b>
                    input#costcost.minIn.nolineinput(name='totalCost' type='text' readonly)

            tr 
                td(colspan=2)
                    button(type='submit' style='width:100%; padding:5px 0px;') Buy
```

My javascript file looks like this:

```
function addToCart(butt){
var $spendable = $('#spendable');

var balance  = Number( $spendable.text() );
var itmCost  = Number($(butt).prev().prev().text());
var boughtItems = $('.firstline').length;
if(balance > itmCost && boughtItems < 4){
    var imgSrc   = $(butt).parent().prev().attr('src');
    var specific = $(butt).prev().val();
    var specificL= $(butt).prev().text();
    var itmName  = $(butt).prev().prev().prev().text();
    var itmType  = $(butt).parent().parent().parent().prop('id');
    var purchCost= Number( $('#purchCost .minIn').val() );

    //create a demo
    if (itmType == 'Treat' || itmType == 'Prize'){
        alert(itmType);
        $('#cartcontainer table tbody').prepend("<tr class='firstline'><td class='smtd' rowspan=2 ><img class='demo' src='" + imgSrc + "'></img></td><td><input type='text' class='nolineinput' name='itmName' value='" + specific +"|" + itmName + "' readonly></input></td><tr><td><div class='minidiv'><p>" + Number(itmCost) + "</p></div><div class='microdiv'><input id='chck' type = 'checkbox' name = 'itmKind' onclick='remove(this)'  checked></input></div></td></tr>")

        if(boughtItems ==0){
            $('#buyit').show()
        }
    }else{
        $('#cartcontainer table tbody').prepend("<tr class='firstline'><td class='smtd' rowspan=2 ><img class='demo' src='" + imgSrc + "'></img></td><td><input type='text' class='nolineinput' name='itmName' value='" + itmName +"| " + specificL + "' readonly></input></td><tr><td><div class='minidiv'><p>" + Number(itmCost) + "</p></div><div class='microdiv'><input class='chck' type = 'checkbox' name = 'itmKind' value='" + itmCost + "' onclick='remove(this)' checked></input></div></td></tr>");


        if(boughtItems ==0){
            $('#buyit').show()
        }
    }
    var total= purchCost + itmCost;
    $('#purchCost .minIn').val(total);
    $spendable.text( balance-itmCost);
}else if (boughtItems >= 4){
    alert("You've reached the max amount of item\n you can purchase. Buy more next week!")
}else {
    alert('Sorry you do not have enough\n points to purchase this item.')
}
```

}

Also I should mention I'm using body-parser and when `i` `console.log( req.body)` the only thing `i` get back is `{totalCost:'1500'}` but what I wish to see is: `{itmName:'Caprisun', itmKind:'Cherry', totalCost:'1500'}`

Comment: i don't think your issue is with `nodeJs` , it's not showing what you want because it's not getting the data from your `form`, when you add the elements, can you see them in the `html` if you inspect your cart ( the form )?

Comment: Yes I can see each tr, td, input that was added when I inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind solved it on my own. The table should have been created inside the form. Table, tbody , tr, td should've all been together like so:

```
    form
         table
              tbody
                   tr
                     td Total
                     td
                        input(type='text' name='itemName')
```